# Validations Rule - picklist value can not be 'ABC'

Tags: validation-rule

I have the following picklist value:

- AAA
- BBB
- CCC
- ABC

I'm writing validation on the `location__c` picklist and the rule is that, 
Location can not be 'ABC'.

I have the following rule but the problem with this is that, it fires even if I do not select any value from picklist or it also fires if I select the picklist value to be AAA or BBB or CCC....

What i'm doing wrong here?

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Lead'), 
AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(location__c, "ABC")), 
OR( 
    $Profile.Name == "System Administrator" 
  ) 
 ) 
)
```

Comment: Is this picklist is multi-select?

Comment: its not multi select

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your intent, you don't want to let a "normal user" select the Location ABC. This means that you should check for the lead status, if the value is being set, the Location is the forbidden value, and the user is not a system administrator. The final validation rule should look like this:

```
ISPICKVAL(Status,'Lead') &&
(ISNEW() || ISCHANGED(Location__c)) &&
ISPICKVAL(Location,"ABC") &&
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator"
```

Remember, a validation rule fires when the result of the formula is TRUE.

Comment: +1 for `(ISNEW() || ISCHANGED(Location__c)) &&`, that's an interesting idea that I might start working into my validations. Is there a performance benefit?

Comment: 1+ for ISNEW() and also I personally like to use `&&` as appose to  `AND`

Comment: @martin I usually use that design because I don't want a user to *set* the value (only admins can), but I want them to be able to edit the record even with that value already previously set.

Comment: I tried your approach but I still be able to save the record with ABC, which is what I do not want.

Comment: What I really like about it is how it essentially declares the fields that the validation rule operates on right at the beginning; putting that logic in the middle of the validation rule can be harder to spot when maintaining the rule. Why not add in Status then?  `(ISNEW() || ISCHANGED(Location__c) || ISCHANGED(Status)) && ISPICKVAL(Status,'Lead') && ISPICKVAL(Location,"ABC") &&
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator"`

Comment: @NickKahn - Are you using a system admin profile or not setting the Status to "Lead" because the VR should fire appropriately according to your criteria

Answer (score 1):

Remove NOT operator and rule will be like this:

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Lead'), 
AND(ISPICKVAL(location__c, "ABC"),     
    $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator" 
  ) 
 )
```

Comment: with the above code i able to save the record with ABC which is not what i want

Answer (score 0):

Here, the `OR` isn't really doing anything for you. The second `AND` is also effectively not helping, since it is chained with another and. Your validation rule boils down to:

```
AND(
   ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Lead'), 
   NOT(ISPICKVAL(location__c, "ABC")), 
   $Profile.Name == "System Administrator" 
)
```

Since you *don't* want `ABC` to be selected, you should remove the `NOT` from the formula. Also since you want to leave an exception for users whose profile has the name `System Administrator`, you should add a `NOT` function to that condition (so that this validation effectively do not apply to them):

```
AND(
   ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Lead'), 
   ISPICKVAL(location__c, "ABC"), 
   NOT($Profile.Name == "System Administrator")
)
```

Comment: did not work, I was able to save the record with ABC

Comment: @NickKahn the first formula is logically equivalent to what was posted in the question, I wanted to simplify it so the op could see more clearly what their formula was doing. The second one should work though.

Comment: sorry did not work your approach